# */?> string appearing in text

Tags: magento-1.9, file, conversion

The string `*/?>` (asterisk slash question-mark greater-than) is appearing in my texts after moving a magento installation over to my own ubuntu server (It previously was on an OVH shared server).

[image: strange string appearing in text]

It looks like a php end tag, but I don't understand why.
I have not changed any file when transferring my installation, and when it was hosted on the previous server, I had none of these issues.
I thought it could be line-endings, and tried using dos2unix, but I'm not sure It did anything.

I remember changing a setting about line-endings in my IDE (phpstorm) recently, which is why I thought about it, and I don't see what else it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on "**short tags**" being disabled on your new server.

In Magento1 you shoud always use `<?php` and you probably have just `<?` inside that template.

You can fix it (best option) or ask for your new provider to enable short tags.

Comment: That was it! I had to try a few times (multiple php.ini files and multiple lines with "short_open_tag" to enable), restarted my server and it's good now. I guess OVH turns short tags on by default.

I also realized the */ was the end of comments, because weirdly most of the times I used the short_tags was to be able to use the /**/ syntax.